# Effects of image quality/resolution in feature extraction

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction

I am working on a project which identifies objects after capturing their images on Android platform. For this, I extracted features of sample images such as compactness, rectangularity, elongation, eccentricity, roundness, sphericity, lobation, and hu moments. After then, random tree is used as classifier. As I used pictures gathered from Google which are not in high resolution for creating my classifier, captured images of size 1280x720 gives 19/20 correct results when the image is cropped.

However, when I capture images of large sizes such as about 5 megapixels, and crop them for identification, the number of obtained correct results dramaticaly decreases.

Do I need to extract features of images with high resolution and train them in order to get accurate results when high resolution pictures are captured? Is there a way of adjusting extracted features related to the image resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Some feature descriptors are sensitive to scaling.  Others, like [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) and [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF), are not.  If you expect the resolution (or scale) of your images to change, it's best to use scale-invariant feature descriptors.

If you use feature descriptors that are not scale-invariant, you can still get decent results by normalizing the resolution of your images.  Try scaling the 5 megapixel images to 1280x720 -- do the classification results improve?